# How can I separate a separable function

Tags: pattern-matching

I have a separable function $f[x,y]$, and I would like to find two functions $g[x]$ and $h[y]$ with

$f[x,y]=g[x] h[y]$

where $g[x]$ doesn't depend on $y$ and $h[y]$ doesn't depend on $x$. Ideally, $g$ and $h$ should have the same magnitude, to prevent overflows/underflows. I have a hackish approach that works, but involves a lot of manual labor.

Background: $f[x,y]$ is a filter kernel I want to apply to an image, and using two separate 1d-filters is much more efficient.

My first approach was to start with $g[x]=f[x,0]$. But that doesn't work for e.g. $f[x,y]=\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2 \sigma ^2}} x y}{2 \pi  \sigma ^6}$

Currently, I have a function that "removes" $x$ or $y$ from $f[x,y]$ using pattern matching:

```
removeSymbol[f_, s_] := f //. {s^_ + a_ -> a, s^_.*a_ -> a}
```

but that means I have to manually adjust this pattern for different f's.

Is there a more elegant way to do this? $f[x,y]$ is usually a derivative of a gaussian, e.g.

```
gaussian[x_,y_] := 1/(2 π σ^2) Exp[-((x^2 + y^2)/(2 σ^2))]
f[x_,y_] := D[gaussian[x,y], x, y]
```

Comment: Since you "have to manually adjust this pattern for different f's" it would be helpful to see some different `f` functions.

Comment: Did you check whether the built-in `GaussianFilter[image,r,{nx,ny}]` would work for you? It might be sufficiently fast that you don't need to separate your kernel.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Ideally it would work for any function, but all the functions I've used so far were various derivatives of gaussian, `D[gaussian[x,y], x]`, `D[gaussian[x,y], x,x,y]` and so on

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: I'm using `GaussianFilter` when I'm prototyping an algorithm in Mathematica. But I have to build the filter kernels manually when I write the final version in C.

Comment: OK, I see. Makes sense.

Comment: Another version: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/224888/69875

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I would take a logarithmic derivative with respect to one variable - it should be then independent of the other one, then integrate it back over the first variable and exponentiate. The second function is found by plain division. Here is the code:

```
ClearAll[getGX];
getGX[expr_, xvar_, yvar_] :=
  With[{dlogg = D[Log[expr], xvar] // FullSimplify},
     Exp[Integrate[dlogg, xvar]] /; FreeQ[dlogg, yvar]];

Clear[getHY];
getHY[expr_, xvar_, yvar_] := FullSimplify[(#/getGX[#, xvar, yvar]) &[expr]]
```

A test function:

```
ftest[x_, y_] := (x^2 + 1)*y^3 *Exp[-x - y]
```

Now,

```
getGX[ftest[x,y],x,y]

(* E^-x (1+x^2)  *)

getHY[ftest[x,y],x,y]

(* E^-y y^3 *)
```

The integration constant ambiguity translates into an ambiguity of how you split the function, since this operation is only defined up to a multiplicative constant factor by which you can multiply one function, and divide the other one.

Comment: Dumb question: How can this work if `expr` can be negative and `Log` is only defined for positive values? Obviously it works, but I can't see why.

Comment: @nikie `Log` is defined in the complex plane, not just real line. So, you can think of it as if I have analytically continued our function. But, we don't have to be so fancy - just replace the logarithmic derivative by `D[expr,xvar]/expr`, and you don't have to think of this issue then.

Comment: Of course, I didn't think of complex numbers. But it even works if `expr` is zero. And neither `Log[expr]` nor `D[expr,xvar]/expr` is defined for `expr=0`. And still, it gives the right result.

Comment: when the expression can't be separated, the call does not even go through. Why is that? Should not these function return {} or such in this case? For example `getGX[1/(x +y),x,y]`  Mathematica just echo the input back to the screen.  This makes it little hard to check if the expression was separated or not?

Comment: And here is another strange result for something that can't be separated `getHY[3 y + Sin[x], x, y]` now Mathematica echos this: `(3 y+Sin[x])/getGX[3 y+Sin[x],x,y]`. How do you suggest the correct way one should check the result for the cases when the expression can't be separated?

Comment: @Nasser "when the expression can't be separated, the call does not even go through. Why is that?" - because of the way I have written the function, particularly the condition `FreeQ[dlogg, yvar]`. "How do you suggest the correct way one should check the result for the cases when the expression can't be separated?" - I wouldn't know off hand, and alas have no time right now to look closer into it.

Comment: fyi, I have a case where it does not seem to produce correct splitting. Here it is: `expr = (x^2*y + y)*y^3*Exp[-x - y + 1]*3^(-x - y)*Sqrt[x^2*y - y];` now `getHY[expr,x,y]` gives expression which contains both x and y in it: `(3^-y E^(1 - y) y^4 Sqrt[(-1 + x^2) y])/Sqrt[1 - x^2]`. The splitting of this expression should be: `xPart = (x^2 + 1) Sqrt[x^2 - 1] Exp[-x] 3^(-x)` and `yPart = y^(9/2) Exp[-y + 1] 3^(-y)` May be I should open a new question on this. Not sure now.

Comment: @Nasser The dependence on `x` in your above result is merely a complex phase. If both multipliers under the square root are non-negative, you can do `FullSimplify[expr/getGX[expr, x, y], Assumptions -> y > 0 && x >= 1 ]`, which results in an expression that depends on `y` only. Such issues are inevitable given that variables are generally considered as complex numbers in Mathematica, and for some expressions one would need extra conditions to ensure they are real and can be factored. Perhaps I should've mentioned that in the post.

Comment: You are right, Here is a small example of where assumptions are needed. `f=Sqrt[x y]`, splitting gives `Sqrt[x]` and `Sqrt[x y]/Sqrt[x]`  but the second one can be simplified to `Sqrt[y]` only under assumption that `x>0`.  I found paper that takes about method, very similar to what you show but was not too clear for me to follow all the details. You might be interested in it. Here is the link https://arxiv.org/ftp/math/papers/0210/0210167.pdf

Comment: @Nasser Thanks, I will have a look when I get a spare moment.

Answer (score 14):

What I'd do:

```
gaussian[x_, y_] := 1/(2 π σ^2) Exp[-((x^2 + y^2)/(2 σ^2))];
f[x_, y_] = D[gaussian[x, y], x, y]

Exp[Select[Expand[PowerExpand[Log[Together[f[x, y]]]]], #]] & /@
    {FreeQ[#, x | y] &, ! FreeQ[#, x] &, ! FreeQ[#, y] &}
{1/(2 Pi σ^6), E^(-(x^2/(2 σ^2))) x, E^(-(y^2/(2 σ^2))) y}
```

The snippet separates out the constant factor, the factors with `x`, and the factors with `y`.

More examples:

```
f = -Pi Cos[x]^2 Sin[y]^3/E;
Exp[Select[Expand[PowerExpand[Log[Together[f]]]], #]] & /@
    {FreeQ[#, x | y] &, ! FreeQ[#, x] &, ! FreeQ[#, y] &}
{-Pi/E, Cos[x]^2, Sin[y]^3}
```

We see that negative constant factors are reproduced.

```
f = w[x] z[y];
Exp[Select[Expand[PowerExpand[Log[Together[f]]]], #]] & /@
    {FreeQ[#, x | y] &, ! FreeQ[#, x] &, ! FreeQ[#, y] &}
{1, w[x], z[y]}
```

The implicit constant factor of `1` is detected.

Comment: Great! I had to add `Together[f[x,y]]` to make it work for `D[gauss, x, x]`, but this looks very promising.

Comment: Ah, yes. I've added it to my snippet.

Comment: (I wish I knew why my answer seems to be less optimal than Leonid's for readers, given the voting patterns...)

Comment: I think that my answer is based more on Mathematics than Mathematica. Which is more optimal is of course subjective.

Comment: @Leonid: I don't know, it's just the basic idea of take a logarithm, pick out terms, and exponentiate... I didn't even have to differentiate/integrate here, and the `*Expand[]` and `Together[]` functions just expedite the separation for `Select[]`.

Comment: What I mean is that my algorithm can, for example, be also applied numerically, for function which is defined numerically, where the notions of `Expand`, `Together` etc make no sense. Actually, `Expand` and `Together`, as well as other operations such as `PowerExpand`, `FreeQ`, don't have a well-defined mathematical meaning, and are only defined in Mathematica. Again, this does not answer which solution is more optimal, but it seems that mine is more universal in the sense that its semantics largely does not depend on a particular tool used to implement it (Mathematica here).

Comment: I upvoted both. And I really like this solution, because selecting factors out of a list seems far more intuitive than all those derivatives and integrals. But I do see advantages in @Leonid's answer: For example, it works for sums, even if they can't be factored by `Together` (Example: `f[x_, y_] := Expand[(x*(y + 1))^5]`). Taking the log to get a list of the factors only works if the original expression is a product. Taking the logarithmic derivative works for sums, too.

Answer (score 3):

While the two existing answers are good, I've always approached this sort of problem with `FactorList` and there should be an answer showing how to use this old *Mathematica* function in this way.  Much time having passed since this question was asked, I'll use current tools to process the list of factors.

I decided to separate the task into two parts, which makes the solution a little more complicated than necessary.  OTOH, I've sometimes wanted to know the factors, including ones that cannot put in the form $g(x)h(y)$, separated by type.

```
ClearAll[sepFac, sepParts, dependsOn];
sepParts[expr_, vars_List] := With[{
      factors = GroupBy[FactorList[expr], 
        Function[fac, 
         Pick[dependsOn @@ vars, Internal`DependsOnQ[fac, #] & /@ vars]]
        ],
      apply = Function[{h, lev}, Apply[h, #, lev] &]},
   apply[Times, {1}]@ apply[Power, {2}]@ factors
   ];
sepFac::nonsep = "The factor `` could not be separated.";
sepFac[expr_, vars_List] := With[{parts = sepParts[expr, vars]},
   Message[sepFac::nonsep, #] & /@ 
    Values@KeySelect[parts, Length[#] >= 2 &];
   (MapAt[dependsOn[] # &, (* multiply first by constant factor *)
     dependsOn /@ vars,
     1] /. parts
     ) /; Max[Length /@ Keys[parts]] <= 1
   ];
```

Examples:

```
gaussian[x_, y_] := 1/(2 π σ^2) Exp[-((x^2 + y^2)/(2 σ^2))]
sepFac[D[gaussian[x, y], x, y], {x, y}]
```

> ```
> (*
>   {(E^(-(x^2/(2 σ^2))) x)/(2 π σ^6), 
>    E^(-(y^2/(2 σ^2))) y}
> *)
> ```

```
sepFac[(x + y) x y, {x, y}]
```

> ```
> sepFac::nonsep :  The factor x+y could not be separated.
>
> (*  sepFac[x y (x + y), {x, y}]  *)
> ```

```
sepParts[(x + y) x y, {x, y}]
```

> ```
> (*
>   <|dependsOn[] -> 1, dependsOn[x] -> x, dependsOn[y] -> y, 
>    dependsOn[x, y] -> x + y|>
> *)
> ```