# Separating variables in an expression

Tags: list-manipulation, symbols, variable

Given a non-polynomial expression such as:

```
expr = x z Sin[x] Sin[y]
```

and that we know that the variables are:

```
var = {x,y,z}
```

... is there a neat way to express `expr` as:

```
{x Sin[x], Sin[y], z}
```

i.e. with the $x$ terms separated out, the $y$ terms separated out and the $z$ terms separated out ... if that separation is possible. The order does not matter ... what matters is that if the function is separable into $x$, $y$ and $z$, then that we separate the output into parcels containing just $x$, just $y$ and just $z$. If it helps, am happy to assume that `expr` is a product of terms.

Most of the functions I have looked at (like `MonomialList` or `Collect`) seem to assume polynomial expressions.

I was thinking of something like:  `expr /. Times -> List` followed by some `FreeQ` checks, but it might be messy, and I was wondering if anyone has a neater approach?

**Second example**

```
  expr2 = x z Sin[x] Sin[y+z]
```

should return:

```
 {x Sin[x], z Sin[y+z]}
```

Comment: What should happend with the non-separable parts? E.g. `expr2 = x z Sin[x] Sin[y + z]`?

Comment: [Dupe?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8142)

Comment: Thanks @MariusLadegårdMeyer  The non-separable parts should be left NOT separated. So for your `expr2`, as:  {`x Sin[x]`, `z Sin[y+z]}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
expr = x z Sin[x] Sin[y];

f = Variables[Level[#, {-1}]] &;
```

If the order is not important

```
Times @@@ GatherBy[List @@ expr, f]

(*  {x Sin[x], z, Sin[y]}  *)
```

If you want them ordered by variable

```
SortBy[Times @@@ GatherBy[List @@ expr, f], f]

(*  {x Sin[x], Sin[y], z}  *)
```

**EDIT:** To address both cases

```
separate[expr_] := 
 List @@ expr //. {s___, v1_, m___, v2_, e___} /;
    Intersection @@ (f /@ {v1, v2}) != {} :> {s, v1*v2, m, e}
```

First case

```
expr = x z Sin[x] Sin[y];

separate[expr]

(*  {x Sin[x], z, Sin[y]}  *)
```

Or

```
separate[expr] // SortBy[#, f] &

(*  {x Sin[x], Sin[y], z}  *)
```

Second case

```
expr2 = x z Sin[x] Sin[y + z];

separate[expr2]

(*  {x Sin[x], z Sin[y + z]}  *)
```

Comment: That is very nice! Thanks

Comment: @Bob Hanlon does this work on the second example he posted?

Comment: It sure does - and it is particularly elegant too!  @BobHanlon 's new second solution is a treat - it took me a while to digest ... but in essence, it says: ........ "while the variables in different terms are intersecting, join the intersecting terms together ..."

Answer (score 1):

Probably not as elegant as you want, but it's relatively short. Using

```
expr = x z Sin[x] Sin[y];
vars = {x, y, z};
```

we do

```
Table[Select[expr, ! FreeQ[#1, var] &], {var, vars}]
(* {x Sin[x], Sin[y], z} *)
```

Comment: `Cases[expr, _Symbol, Infinity]` will include numeric symbols, e.g., Pi, E, GoldenRatio.

Comment: @BobHanlon. True. Then I guess mine really only generally works if we have the variables already. I think I'll go ahead and remove that part.