# Factoring a multi-variable function into single-variable terms

Tags: functions, algebraic-manipulation

Suppose I have an **arbitrary** function $f$ of $n$ variables.

For simplicity, let's assume that $n=3$. Suppose that I have its explicit form, $f(x,y,z)$ and I want to expand it into a sum of terms, each of which is separable in all variables, i.e.

$$f(x,y,z)=\sum_i a_i(x)b_i(y)c_i(z).$$

How would I do that? No additional properties are required and the multiplicative constant can be either factored out, distributed over all 3 functions in each term, or included only in one of the functions, it's irrelevant. What's relevant is that $a_i$,$b_i$ and $c_i$ depend *only* on a *single* variable.

I tried using [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/151189/decompose-many-variables-function-as-sum-of-single-variable-functions-schmidt), but it doesn't work with more complicated functions. In my cases, I need to separate a mess with a lot of $\Gamma$-functions. I don't really care about the *form* of these single-variable functions, they can be in closed form (if it exists) or they can be expressed through a series expansion, as long as it's exact.

Comment: An example where the referenced link doesn't work would be helpful.

Comment: Anything with a $\Gamma$, even something as simple as $\Gamma(x-y)$ or $\Gamma(xy)$.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `Series[Gamma[x - y], {x, 1, 3}, {y, -1, 3}]` or `Series[Gamma[x y], {x, 1, 3}, {y, 1, 3}]`?

Comment: That doesn't give me the exact solution, it truncates the series, I need the explicit form, something like `SeriesCoefficient[Gamma[x y], {x, 1, n}, {y, 1, m}]` but this doesn't seem to work for anything more complicated than a polynomial.

Comment: Might want to check work by Frederick Chapman, Keith Geddes, and one or two others on "Geddes series". But I'm not sure thier approach will recover the exact form as opposed to a tensor product approximation for some region.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely check it out!