How can we obtain the first integrals of Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs?
For example, there are two Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs, and the process for solving their first integrals is as follows.
(1)  $ \frac{dx}{2xy^2 + xz} = \frac{dy}{-yz - 3x^3y} = \frac{dz}{3x^3z - 2y^2z}.$
Dt[z]/(3 x^3 z - 2 y^2 z) == Dt[x]/(2 x y^2 + x z) == Dt[y]/(-3 x^3 y - y z)

Thus,
$ \frac{dz}{3x^3z - 2y^2z} = \frac{ydx + xdy}{xy(2y^2 - 3x^3)} = \frac{3x^3dx + 2ydy - dz}{0}. $
From the first equation, the first integral is obtained:
$ - \frac{dz}{z} = \frac{ydx + xdy}{xy} = \frac{dx}{x} + \frac{dy}{y}, \quad xyz = c_1. $
From the third equation, the first integral is obtained:
$ 3x^2dx + 2ydy - dz = 0, \quad x^3 + y^2 - z = c_2, $
where c1 an c2 are integration constants.
(2) $
\frac{dx}{2yz} = \frac{dy}{-xz} = \frac{dz}{-xy},
$
-(Dt[z]/(x y))==Dt[x]/(2 y z)== -(Dt[y]/-x z)

Clearly, the first integrals are
$
\frac{dx}{2yz} = \frac{dy}{-xz}, \quad 2y^2 + x^2 = c_1
$
and
$
\frac{dy}{-xz} = \frac{dz}{-xy}, \quad z^2 - y^2 = c_2.
$
If we use Mathematica (MMA) programming to solve them, it is straightforward to first use DSolve to solve the Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs and then use Solve to determine the integration constants C[1] and C[2], which are the first integrals. However, many Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs cannot be solved using DSolve, so this method cannot always be used to find the first integrals. Instead, it is often easier to directly use the properties of Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs and solve for the functional relationships between the variables through proportional relationships. Then, the first integrals can be obtained by integration.
My question is whether there exists a built-in function or package capable of adopting a brute-force approach (which would make the code more general rather than specific to a single equation). This method would be similar to the one in textbooks, where one multiplies the numerator and denominator by a coefficient and then adds or subtracts them to form an exact differential. This process would reduce the equations to the forms {dx/f[x] == dy/g[y], dy/h[y] == dz/k[z]} or {dx/f[x] + dy/g[y] + dz/k[z] == 0, dx/h[x] + dy/m[y] + dz/n[z] == 0}, making it possible to directly integrate and obtain two first integrals. Finally, the independence of the first integrals can be verified using the condition that the Jacobian determinant is nonzero.

EDIT 20241207
Thank you for @xzczd's analysis and summary. However, I still believe there should be an algorithm that mimics human thinking in tackling such problems. By observing the characteristics of each term, for example, the code could evaluate the similarities in the denominators (such as common divisors, common multiples, etc.), list a large number of possible factors, and then try them one by one to complete the total differential or separate the variables, ultimately obtaining the total differential or separated form. This method should be able to solve most textbook problems of this type, similar to @Nasser’s algorithm on variable separation.
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/162500/69835

My opinion is, if such general method exists, it should already show up in previous questions. (We see this type of problem is not rare. ) But once again, I sincerely hope I'm wrong.

This is a community wiki, so feel free to revise.

My question is whether there exists a built-in function or package capable of adopting a brute-force approach (which would make the code more general rather than specific to a single equation).

The answer is probably no. So far, solutions showing up in this site fall into three categories.
1. Find explicit solution with DSolve and move the constants to one side with Solve
This method is already mentioned by OP in the body of question.
Advantage:
The method is relatively general.
Disadvantage:
DSolve isn't always able to solve the ODEs explicitly, and the explicit solution isn't always easy to transform to first integral.
Example:

toImplicitSolution

How to obtain the solution of an ODE in implicit form?

Page 112 of Symmetry Analysis of Differential Equations with Mathematica® by Gerd Baumann:




Symbolic solution of first-order quasilinear PDE (Remark section)

2. Hack DSolve and extract intermediate result
This method is similar to the first method, but it avoids dealing with the explicit solution.
Advantage:
The method is relatively general. It may generate simpler solution than the first method, because the step solving for explicit solution is avoided.
Disadvantage:
Implicit solution isn't always generated internally. Advanced programming skill may be needed.
Example:

Coaxing DSolve to produce an implicit solution (Notice Carl Woll, a WRI employee, has taken part in the discussion.)

How to stop DSolve from solving equations

How to get the implicit function solution of ODE?


3. Mathematica aided deduction
Advantage
Slightly simpler than fully manual deduction.
Disadvantage:
Manual analysis is required, the method is not general-purpose.
Example:
Symbolic solution of first-order quasilinear PDE
DSolve cannot solve this system of ODEs with symbolic coefficients

Thank you for your comprehensive analysis and summary. The comment is a bit long, and in order for more people to see it, I've placed it in the question.
