# Re-writing $f(x, y)$ as $g(x)h(y)$

Tags: equation-solving, functions, simplifying-expressions

Is there a general way of re-writing a function of two variables as a product of two functions,

$$f(x, y) = g(x)h(y)$$

Specifically, I’m trying to write an expression,

$$f(x, y) = \frac{a y - x}{y - 1} = g(x) h(y)$$

Comment: Do you mean $f(x,y)=g(x)h(y)$?

Comment: Yes! Let me change

Comment: I guess you can use `Factor`. If it doesn't work, decomposition may be difficult or impossible.

Comment: Ok will read about that function, thanks

Comment: This is like the process in solving separable differential equations, but your specific example is not separable.  A well-written function should so indicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
decompose[
  expr_,
  vars_?(ListQ[#] && Length[#] >= 2 && VectorQ[#, AtomQ] &),
  dom_ : Reals
] := If[
        VectorQ[Keys[#], k \[Function] Length[k] <= 1],
                    {True, Times @@@ Apply[Power, #, {2}]},
        (* Else, do some math.
           True: Decomposable but `FactorList` failed.
           @PleaseCorrectGrammarMistakes *)
        (r \[Function] If[r,
                    {True, <||>},
        (* False: Undecomposable *)
                    {False, Null},
        (* Else: With condition *)
                    {ConditionalExpression[True, r],
                      Null}]
        )@ Resolve[ForAll[vars,
                     FunctionDomain[expr, vars, dom],
                     Reduce[
                       expr^(Length[vars] - 1)*D @@
                          Flatten[{expr, vars}]
                       == Times @@ (D[expr, #] & /@ vars),
                     dom]], dom]
      ] &@GroupBy[
            FactorList[expr],
            vars \[Intersection] Level[#[[1]], {-1}] &
      ]
```

For example:

```
decompose[(a y - x)/(y - 1), {x, y}]
```

> ```
> {ConditionalExpression[True, a == 0], Null}
> ```

```
decompose[
 (Log[x] + (x - 1)/Sqrt[x]) (y^2 + Sqrt[y] + y) // Expand,
 {x, y}
 ]
```

> ```
> {True, <|{} -> 1, {x} -> (-1 + x + Sqrt[x] Log[x])/Sqrt[x], {y} -> 
>    Sqrt[y] (1 + Sqrt[y] + y^(3/2))|>}
> ```

```
decompose[
 (Log[x] + (x - 1)/Sqrt[x]) (y^2 + Sqrt[y] + x y) // Expand,
 {x, y}
 ]
```

> ```
> {False, Null}
> ```

```
decompose[
 2 x^2 (1 + y) z Sqrt[z] // Expand,
 {x, y, z}]
```

> ```
> {True, <|{} -> 2, {x} -> x^2, {z} -> z^(3/2), {y} -> 1 + y|>}
> ```

```
decompose[
 2 x^2 (1 + y) z Sqrt[x + z] // Expand,
 {x, y, z}]
```

> ```
> {False, Null}
> ```

Comment: Thanks. It seems my expression is not decomposable.

Comment: Your answer is very good. I would like to know if there is any theoretical proof for this question. If so, it is better to give a link to this textbook.

Comment: @PleaseCorrectGrammarMistakes Thanks. But I am just taking advantage of `FactorList` and no math is involved. I've seen your answer and perhaps you can turn it into code.

Answer (score 3):

I found that there are similar questions in [the course of mathematical analysis](http://book.ucdrs.superlib.net/views/specific/2929/bookDetail.jsp?dxNumber=000008344714&d=646D9E019A3E95FCBD90D5C748FFE558&fenlei=130110) compiled by **史济怀** of China. I pasted the questions and the reference answers as follows:

[image]

On page 492 of this book, we can find a brief reference answer:

[image]

In short, if $u(x,y)$ can be decomposed into the product of two monomials, then the second mixed partial derivative of $\ln u(x,y)$ should be 0.

Comment: 数学分析这块快忘光了.但如果$u(x,y)$可取负值,结论还成立吗?

Comment: @SneezeFor16Min 经过询问哆嗒数学群（群号128709478）里面的北京大学的小米（QQ2498412165），他说仍然成立，只是多一些讨论罢了。

Comment: Okay, *I think we should stay in English*. Will you post code from this proof? If not, I'll update my answer. :)

Comment: @SneezeFor16Min 我不贴了，你把你的答案更新就好了。