# How to factorize $f(x,y)$ into $f_1(x)f_2(y)$?

Tags: functions, factorization, products

Suppose we have a real function $f:\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and we would like to know if this function factorizes into $f(x,y)=f_1(x)f_2(y)$ for some real functions $f_1,f_2$. Is there an easy way of doing this in mathematica ? The program would return a set $f_1,f_2$ that does the job if they exist and would say it is not possible if such $f_1,f_2$ do not exist. I've been playing around with the "Collect" command, but I haven't figured out a way to get what I want.

Example: $f(x,y)=xy^2 - 4y^2 - xy+4y+x-4$ can be factorized into $(x-4)(y^2-y+1)$, so the program would return $f_1(x)=x-4, f_2(y)=y^2-y+1$. But $f(x,y) = xy+1$ cannot be factorized, so it would return impossible.

EDIT: I do not suppose that $f$ is separable, I would like to find out if it is, and in that case, get the factors $f_1,f_2$.

EDIT2: If I want to check the separability of a function using the proposed technique below, here is what I get:

Let's take a function that is NOT seperable:

```
ftest[t_, s_] := (s (t - T[1]) (s t - t T[1] + (T[1] - T[2]) T[2]))/Sqrt[s t (s - T[1]) (t - T[1]) (s - T[2]) (t - T[2]) (s - T[1] + T[2]) (t - T[1] +T[2])]
```

Checking separability using the proposed code by taking the product of $f_1$ by $f_2$:

```
Simplify[getGX[ftest[x, y], x, y]*getHY[ftest[x, y], x, y] - ftest[x, y]] == 0
```

This returns true, although ftest is not separable.

Comment: Include a practical example of what you are working with, and the result you expect.

Comment: If [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8142) does not suit your needs, edit your question to explain why.

Comment: It does not, I explained why

Comment: Your factorization of $x y^2-4y^2-xy+4y+x-1$ doesn't appear to be correct: expanding $ (x-4)(y^2-y-1) $ yields $ x y^2-4 y^2 -x y +4 y +x -4 $.

Comment: You're right, it's a typo, I'll correct it!

Comment: The Q&A @J.M. linked works for me.  Leonid's solution does not assume $f$ is separable. You just have to check `getGX` evaluated (does not return with `Head` the same as `getGX`).

Comment: `With[{gx = getGX[ftest[x, y], x, y]}, FreeQ[gx, getGX] && Simplify[gx*getHY[ftest[x, y], x, y] - ftest[x, y]] == 0]` returns `False`.  (Check the result of `getGX`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(too long for comment).

> It does not, I explained why

Both answers in the link given by J. M.'s ennui work for me.

[How can I separate a separable function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8142/how-can-i-separate-a-separable-function)

If you show an example of why it does not work and how, that will help.

Here is an example from one of the answers there

```
ClearAll[getGX];
getGX[expr_, xvar_, yvar_] := 
  With[{dlogg = D[Log[expr], xvar] // FullSimplify}, 
   Exp[Integrate[dlogg, xvar]] /; FreeQ[dlogg, yvar]];
Clear[getHY];
getHY[expr_, xvar_, yvar_] := FullSimplify[(#/getGX[#, xvar, yvar]) &[expr]]
```

And now do

```
f = x*y^2 - 4*y^2 - x*y + 4*y + x - 4;
getGX[f, x, y]
getHY[f, x, y] // Expand
```

gives the factors

[image]

If it can't factor it, the function returns unevaluated. So you treat that as the  "impossible" case.

[image]

So why exactly the above not work for you?

**edit**

> I edited my question with more details about that code

You are not using the code in the answers quite correctly. Need to check if it fails or not, by checking if the result returns unevaluated or not. I would start with `getGX` first, and check if that evaluates or not. Then if it does, now call `getHY`.

One way could be

```
sep[f_, x_, y_] := Module[{fx, fy},
   fx = getGX[f, x, y];
   If[Head[fx] === getGX,
    Return["impossible", Module];
    ];
   fy = getHY[f, x, y];
   {fx, fy}
   ];
```

And now

```
ftest[t_, s_] := (s (t - T[1]) (s t - t T[1] + (T[1] - T[2]) T[2]))/
  Sqrt[s t (s - T[1]) (t - T[1]) (s - T[2]) (t - T[2]) (s - T[1] + 
      T[2]) (t - T[1] + T[2])];
sep[ftest[x, y], x, y]
```

gives

```
"impossible"
```

and

```
sep[x*y^2 - 4*y^2 - x*y + 4*y + x - 4, x, y]
```

gives

```
{-4 + x, 1 + (-1 + y) y}
```

Comment: I edited my question with more details about that code

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to show that your function is not separable by substituting specific values

```
ftest[t_, s_] := (s (t - T[1]) (s t - t T[1] + (T[1] - T[2]) T[2]))/
  Sqrt[s t (s - T[1]) (t - T[1]) (s - T[2]) (t - T[2]) (s - T[1] + 
  T[2]) (t - T[1] + T[2])]
```

For example

```
M = Table[ftest[i, j], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}] /. T[i_] -> 3 i^2 + 7 i + 4;

MatrixRank[M]
(* 2 *)
```

Since the rank is greater than 1, it cannot be written as the sum of less than 2 separable terms.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8142/how-can-i-separate-a-separable-function)'s [a similar post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/224888/42417).

```
decompose[expr_, vars_?(ListQ[#] && Length[#] >= 2 &)] := 
 If[VectorQ[Keys[#], k |-> Length[k] <= 1], 
    Times @@@ Apply[Power, #, {2}], Indeterminate] &@
  GroupBy[FactorList[expr], vars \[Intersection] Level[#[[1]], {-1}] &]
decompose[(Log[x] + (x - 1)/Sqrt[x]) (y^2 + Sqrt[y] + y) // 
  Expand, {x, y}]
```

On page 411 of [this book](http://book.ucdrs.superlib.net/views/specific/2929/bookDetail.jsp?dxNumber=000008344714&d=06E6DA988FDE0EF4B1E5827BE35DE991&fenlei=130110), there is a similar exercise proof:

[image]

In short, if $u(x,y)$ can be decomposed into the product of two monomials, then the second mixed partial derivative of $\ln u(x,y)$ should be 0.

For the function `ftest[t, s]`, we find the second partial derivative of `Log[ftest[t, s]]`:

```
D[Log[ftest[t, s]], t, s] // FullSimplify
```

It can be seen that only when `T[1] = T[2]` or `T[2]=0`, its second mixed partial derivative is `0`, so only when `T[1] = T[2]` or `T[2]=0`, `ftest[t, s]` can be decomposed.