# Very odd results from DSolve for nonlinear ODE

Tags: differential-equations, functions, nonlinear

I am solving

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{y^6-2x^2}{xy^2\left(2y^3+x\right)}$$

In Mathematica 12.2.0.0 on Windows 10, x86, 64-bit

```
  DSolve[{y'[x] == (-2*x^2 + y[x]^6)/(x*y[x]^2*(x + 2*y[x]^3))}, y[x], x]
```

It returns a bunch of root functions like

$$\left.y(x)\to \sqrt[3]{\text{Root}\left[7290 \text{$\#$1}^2 e^{5 c_1} x^8-10125 \text{$\#$1}^3 e^{5 c_1} x^7+945 \text{$\#$1}^4 e^{5 c_1} x^6+2079 \text{$\#$1}^5 e^{5 c_1} x^5-735 \text{$\#$1}^6 e^{5 c_1} x^4-55 \text{$\#$1}^7 e^{5 c_1} x^3+75 \text{$\#$1}^8 e^{5 c_1} x^2-15 \text{$\#$1}^9 e^{5 c_1} x+\text{$\#$1}^{10} e^{5 c_1}+14580 \text{$\#$1} e^{5 c_1} x^9+x^{15}-17496 e^{5 c_1} x^{10}\&,1\right]}\right\}$$

I was not expecting this, but using step-by-step, we get something like what I was expecting

[image]

First, what are you supposed to do with all those root function outputs?

Is there some way to get the step-by-step output?

Comment: Well, this is essentially a duplicate of the question you asked 4 years ago, and the method under that post still works, doesn't it?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/137598/1871

Comment: @xzczd: Thanks for that pointer - I had totally forgotten about posting that so long ago. I think this should be closed as a dupe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution by Wolfram alpha step by step is hand crafted. The solution by `DSolve` is not. It is an automated method. It looks like it did root extraction at some point since it does not see the ODE becomes separable.

You did not show the full steps Wolfram alpha used. But this is how I would do it

```
ClearAll[y, x, u, rhs]
ode = y'[x] == (-2*x^2 + y[x]^6)/(x*y[x]^2*(x + 2*y[x]^3));
```

this is isobaric of order 1/3, hence do the following substitution to make it     separable

```
f = y -> Function[{x}, u[x]*x^(1/3)];
newOde = ode /. f
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
rhs = u'[x] /. First@Solve[newOde, u'[x]] /. u[x] -> u
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is separable. isobaric ODE always become separable after the substitution. The rest is now just integration. No need to use `DSolve` at all.

Using Leonid Shifrin code from [how-can-i-separate-a-separable-function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8142/how-can-i-separate-a-separable-function)

```
ClearAll[getGX];
getGX[expr_, xvar_, yvar_] := 
  With[{dlogg = D[Log[expr], xvar] // FullSimplify}, 
   Exp[Integrate[dlogg, xvar]] /; FreeQ[dlogg, yvar]];
Clear[getHY];
getHY[expr_, xvar_, yvar_] := 
 FullSimplify[(#/getGX[#, xvar, yvar]) &[expr]]

fx = getGX[rhs, x, u]
fu = getHY[rhs, x, u]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now just integrate both sides, since now the ode becomes $u'=f(x) f(u)$

```
solU = Integrate[1/fu, u] == Integrate[fx, x] + C[1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

substitute back to get solution of original ode

```
solU /. u -> y[x]/x^(1/3) // Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I do not see how to tell `DSolve` to obtain the same hand crafted solution. Many CAS methods and algorithms do not correspond and follow the same methods we use when solving things by hand due to may reasons.

ps. for working with root objects, see [Root.html](http://Root.html)   and [how-do-i-work-with-root-objects](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects)  but since you have constant of integration in there, you will  not be able to do anything with it in terms of plotting, evaluating numerical value, etc...